# Shell script to divide csv files automatically using thread group count

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter, distributed

Currently I am manually dividing the csv files for distributed testing of Jmeter from 3 machines. But I need a shell script which will automatically divide the csv files based on thread group count

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give unique values for each thread, you can simply do this by changing some values on CSV Data Set Config:

1. Recycle on EOF : False
2. Stop Thread on EOF : True
3. Sharing mode: All Threads

After these values, each thread on your jmx will get unique values from your CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

Normally it's not necessary to split the CSV file for the Thread Groups count, you just need to choose the appropriate [Sharing Mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/csv-data-set-config-in-sharing-mode-made-easy/) of the [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)

As an exception here is an example shell script which splits the CSV file by the number of thread groups in the [.jmx script](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JmxTestPlan):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
threadGroups=`grep -c "\"ThreadGroup\"" test.jmx`
split --suffix-length="${threadGroups}" --additional-suffix=.csv -d --number="l/${threadGroups}" "test.csv" "."/
```

Replace `test.jmx` and `test.csv` with the names/locations of your .jmx and .csv files

it will generate .CSV files in form of `000.csv`, `001.csv`, etc.

More information: [Split Command in Linux with Examples](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/split-command-in-linux-with-examples/)